# Fool a game client to download files locally and not from a remote server

Tags: networking

Is there a way to fool a game client that downloads the graphical files from a remote server to load certain graphical files from my own machine?

It would download files like: http://game.com/game_client/login/bcackground.png
The connection is plain HTML and the domain is of course fake but you get the point.

*Is it possible for a program or script to listen trough the connections the game client uses and block the game client from downloading certain files but instead use the files located at my own machine? (The game client will think it came from the remote server)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically: yes, that is possible.

How easy that is depends on the game client. If it uses its own protocol and an encrypted connection then you are usually out of luck. There are a few examples on the net where a team did similar things after working on it for a year or two. That was fun to watch (is is somewhere on the CCC servers) and fun for the people to do, but quite non trivial.

If the game uses plain HTTP (e.g. a web client) without encryption then you can use a proxy to interfere.

(PS: your link with the game background is broken. It does not show a picture. I just get a 'this domain is for sale').

Comment: Yes, the link was an example and the connection is plain HTTP, encryption is not involved at all.

Comment: Ah. I expected a screenshot of the client, not an existing domain. (And since it resokves it either exists or DNS is broken).